# How to enable compression on an existing Hbase table?

Tags: compression, hbase

I have a very big Hbase table apData, but it was not set as compressed when it was created. Right now it's 1.5TB. So I wanna enable compression feature on this table. I did the following:

```
(1)disable apData
(2)alter apData,{NAME=>'cf1',COMPRESSION=>'snappy'}
(3)enable 'apData'.
```

But when I use `"desc apData"` to see the configuration, it's still showing:

`COMPRESSION => 'NONE'`

Why it didn't take effect? How should I compress the table please, and also make sure that the future data would be compressed automatically when it is inserted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you configure Snappy.
Verify first snappy is loaded in all the nodes. To verify please use this command.

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest
>    hdfs://host/path/to/hbase snappy

Once snappy test is successful. The mentioned above compression should work.

For more detail about configuration and installation of snappy:
http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/snappy.compression.html

Comment: Thank you Vick, do I also need to modify hbase-site.xml to add the following line please:hbase.regionserver.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

Comment: Normally, you don't need to add codes in hbase-site.xml. It should automatically determine. But still you can try this. Did you test snappy is available or not?

Comment: What if this commands throws an error that /hbase is non empty?

Answer (score 6):

HBase will only compress *new* HFiles - either new data you write or the results of compactions

Comment: thank you so much! so is it impossible that I could compact the existing table please? I heard of magior_compact, does that will help to compress the existing data please. the current table is almost 2TB, very headache. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the hbase shell to initiate a major compaction (unifies HFiles and will also use the compression when writing the new files)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to configure HBase to use Snappy.

You can follow steps mentioned in the reference link to enable snappy compression in hbase:
[configure snappy compression with HBase](http://blogs.impetus.com/big_data/big_data_technologies/SnappyCompressionInHBase.do)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

We need to configure HBase to use Snappy if we installed Hadoop and HBase from tarballs; if we installed them from RPM or Debian packages, Snappy requires no HBase configuration.

Depending on the architecture of the machine we are installing on, we have to add one of the following lines to /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh:

```
For 32-bit platforms:
export HBASE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-i386-32

For 64-bit platforms:
export HBASE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
```